# Can Einstein-Hilbert action be derived from symmetry considerations?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, variational-principle, covariance, classical-field-theory

The action of a *free* *relativistic* classical field theory can be derived from *Poincare invariance*, *locality*, and retaining terms quadratic in fields. Is there a similar set of symmetry principles which enable one to write down the [Einstein-Hilbert (EH) action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein%E2%80%93Hilbert_action) $$S_{EH}=\frac{c^4}{16\pi G}\int d^4x \sqrt{-g}R\tag{1}$$ uniquely?

In chapter VII.1, of the QFT book by A. Zee, it is mentioned that

> *The Einstein-Hilbert action is uniquely determined if we require the action to be coordinate invariant and to involve two powers of spacetime derivative.*

which is then justified *a posteriori*. But how does one arrive at the form (1) from scratch and in a neat step-by-step manner?

Comment: possible duplicate: [Can we derive Einstein-Hilbert action through action principle and Levi-Civita connection?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/353424/84967).

Comment: This is true in 4 dimensions if you also require the stress-energy tensor to be divergence-free (along with a lambda term)

Comment: @Slereah, The stress-energy tensor does not appear at the level of the action, so why would it be relevant at all? The 4-dimensional condition seems rather superfluous.

Comment: This is Lovelock's theorem. The action is much more general for $n > 4$.

Comment: Lovelock's theorem is about uniqueness of the Einstein field equations not the Einstein-Hilbert action.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/87937/2451 and links therein.

Comment: By the way, a little dimensional analysis: (M for mass, L for length, T for time duration): [S] = ML²/T. [√|g| d⁴x] = L⁴, [G] = L³/(MT²), [c] = L/T, [R] = 1/L². Thus, [1/(8πG) ∫ R √|g| d⁴x] = (MT²)/L³·L² = MT²/L and ... [c³/(8πG) ∫ R √|g| d⁴x] = (L/T)³·MT²/L = ML²/T = [S]. It's c³/(8πG), not c⁴/(8πG). Almost everybody gets this wrong - even that wall over at Leiden.  c⁴/(8πG), c³/(8πG), c²/(8πG) all appear in the literature - the literature is confused too. Only c³/(8πG) is correct.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, one can reason as follows:

- One wants a diffeomorphism-invariant action, which must be of the form $$ S=\int d^4x\sqrt{-g}L, $$ where $L$ is a scalar in terms of transformation properties.
- Gravity is assumed to be purely metric, so $g_{\mu\nu}$ is the only dynamical variable that can appear in the action.
- So we must look for scalars that can be constructed out of the metric. One is of course $g^{\mu\nu}g_{\mu\nu}=4$, but since we can rescale by constants, this is basically a constant. Normally you wouldn't care about constants, but constants here do contribute, because they get multiplied by the metric determinant.
- At an arbitrary point $p$, you can set up coordinates such that $g_{\mu\nu}(p)=\eta_{\mu\nu}$ and $\partial_\mu g_{\nu\rho}(p)=0$, so there are no scalars that can be constructed out of the metric and its first derivatives. One needs to look for higher derivatives.
- The curvature tensor $R^\rho_{\ \sigma\mu\nu}$ is a good candidate. There are ways to show that the Riemann-tensor is basically unique or "most general" such a tensor, so we don't really need to look futher.
- It should be noted that one reason we don't want the Lagrangian to contain second or higher derivatives is due to [Ostrogradsky instabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ostrogradsky_instability). Ostrogradsky instability, is however avoided, if the Lagrangian is *linear* in the second derivatives.
- It is easy to check that the Riemann curvature tensor is linear in the second derivatives of the metric components.
- One needs to form a scalar out of $R^\rho_{\ \sigma\mu\nu}$, however any scalar produced by squaring a curvature tensor will ruin the linearity in the second derivatives. This rules out $R^{\rho\sigma\mu\nu}R_{\rho\sigma\mu\nu},\ C^{\rho\sigma\mu\nu}C_{\rho\sigma\mu\nu},\ R_{\mu\nu}R^{\mu\nu}$ etc. However the curvature scalar $R=R^\rho_{\mu\rho\nu}g^{\mu\nu}$ is still linear in the second derivatives.
- This gives us $$ L=\alpha R+\beta $$ as a possible scalar Lagrangian, where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are constants. Of course $\beta$ may be zero, $\alpha$ not so much. We factorize as $$ L=\alpha\left(R+\frac{\beta}{\alpha}\right), $$ with $\alpha=\frac{1}{2\kappa}$ and $\beta=-\frac{\Lambda}{\kappa}$ to get $$ L=\frac{1}{2\kappa}\left(R-2\Lambda\right), $$ which is the Lagrangian for the Einstein Field Equation (extended with the cosmological constant), provided that $\kappa=\frac{8\pi G}{c^4}$.